# IIS ARR - Route single request to multiple servers/sites

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

We have a unique situation with a vendor in which they only allow 1 address for PRD traffic and 1 for Non-PRD traffic. Internally, we need to be able to test in 2 environments (call them TST1 and TST2). Since they only allow 1 URL for TST, I figured I would create 2 ARR Rules for the site to rewrite the traffic to both. I ensured 'Stop processing subsequent rules' was disabled.

Upon testing this with a user, I only see traffic for the top (first listed) ARR rule. I am now debating whether ARR rewrites work in the manner I presumed. I am not terribly experienced in IIS ARR.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve the goal of 1 request being routed (somewhat duplicated) to 2 servers simultaneously?